# Set font size of text

Tags: vba, outlook

I send text to Outlook email that shows up in font size 10.

I have it set at 11 as the rest of my email. The signature is set to 11 as well.

I am using this.

```
EBody_tekst = "<font face= Calibri size= 11px color=#000000>" & _
```

But still the text will show up at fontsize 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably you may want to try with this:

```
<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>TEXT</BODY>
```

Comment: @Sjoerd89, you may mark the answer as accepted, by clicking the green checkbox on its left.

Comment: Sorry for being new but i can't see that green checkbox ;)

Comment: @Sjoerd89 in the left margin, right underneath the upvote/downvote buttons next to the answer

Comment: Or check here -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work